# Xamarin iOS Xamarin.Auth Keeps Account data even after uninstalling the Application

Tags: xamarin.ios, account, xamarin.auth

To save user auth credential i've used Xamarin.Auth Account store 
But it keeps the credentials data even after i uninstall application
so the problem is when reinstall new version it would automatically gets logged-in.
How can i clear auth credentials on uninstalling applcation ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: There is no event raised  when the app is uninstalled . What we can do is deleting all data when the app first starts up (after reinstall..)

Comment: @ColeXia, Ok, But then how should i store my credentials so that it gets cleared on uninstalling.

Comment: As I mentioned above , the biggest problem is how to detect the event on uninstalling, unfortunately there is impossible.